# Form Validator Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

i want to ask why my validator is not working with this function, i have tested with other function and it working fine. Below is my code, thank you for helping me because im still new and still learning. As you can see in my code i already have _formkey and i already declare final isValid = _formKey.currentState!.validate();

```
Form(
                          key: _formKey,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              TextFormField(
                                inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                                controller: _reloadEditingController,
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                                autovalidateMode:
                                    AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                                validator: (value) => value!.isEmpty
                                    ? 'Please enter min value'
                                    : null,
                                    
                               
                              Container(
                                width: 320,
                                child: MaterialButton(
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    await initPayment(
                                        email: email,
                                        amount: double.parse(
                                            _reloadEditingController.text),
                                        context: context);
                                  },
                                  color: Color(0xFF006e6e),
                                  elevation: 8,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13),
                                  ),
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          "Reload E-Wallet",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 20),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
```

and below here is my initpayment function

```
Future<void> initPayment(
      {required String email,
      required double amount,
      required BuildContext context}) async {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState!.validate();

    if (isValid) {
      try {
        double s = double.parse(_reloadEditingController.text);
        // 1. Create a payment intent on the server
        final response = await http.post(
            Uri.parse(
                'https://us-central1-fiverr-3402e.cloudfunctions.net/stripePaymentIntentRequest'),
            body: {
              'email': email,
              'amount': (s * 100).toString(),
            });

        final jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
        log(jsonResponse.toString());
        // 2. Initialize the payment sheet
        await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
            paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
          paymentIntentClientSecret: jsonResponse['paymentIntent'],
          merchantDisplayName: 'IIUM Freelance',
          customerId: jsonResponse['customer'],
          customerEphemeralKeySecret: jsonResponse['ephemeralKey'],
        ));
        await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            content: Text('Payment is successful'),
          ),
        );

        try {
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("users")
              .doc(widget.userID)
              .update({"balance": balance + s});
          getUserData();
        } catch (error) {}
      } catch (errorr) {
        if (errorr is StripeException) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              content:
                  Text('An error occured ${errorr.error.localizedMessage}'),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              content: Text('An error occured $errorr'),
            ),
          );
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid double and my validator not working

Comment: I've answered your question. Now, can you check is that working for you

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put the error there, and not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Change your validator like below

```
validator: (value) {
    if(value == null || value!.isEmpty){
            return  'Please enter min value'; 
    } 
    return null
 },
```

Comment: still the same brother , The following FormatException was thrown while handling a gesture:
Invalid double

Comment: The invalid double is not depending on the validator. It's regarding the conversion you're doing. double s = double.parse(_reloadEditingController.text);  You're probably inserting text and try to convert it to double.

Comment: And can you share on which line exactly you're getting that error

Comment: i dont have any error inside my code , it just that my validator is not working.

Comment: I've updated the code. Now, can you look into that.

Comment: still the same , i dont know why. I tested with empty functions the validator working fine , with my initPayment function its not working